# Can I write java code in android xml layout or string values files?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to know if it is possible to write java code in android XML layout or string values files?

I mean something like this:

```
<string name="hello">Utilities.doSomething("Hello World, ActMain!")</string>
<string name="app_name">insurance</string>
```

Comment: You can not. Why do you need it?

Comment: There are several possible reasons for you to do this, but I am interested in only one. Did you use this code to somehow build
 protection of your app from piracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running code from strings.xml can be possible in the following way(Not tested,but a high level idea of doing it)
1.Get the string from strings.xml using R.string.* where * is the name of your string.

2.Use any of the expressions evaluation library to run it.

Again this a very high level idea.You will have to figure out how to do that your self.

[Check the Jel library for it](http://www.gnu.org/software/jel/)

[Or check this list of  evaluation libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it? Apparently, `Eclipse` doesn't show an error in it.So the answer to:

> Can I write java code in android xml layout or string values files?

Is yes.

But you will not get the desired functionality when you execute it. Hence, it's dead code anyhow. So, ultimately, you can write it, but no use of it.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to write code in strings xml or in layouts and get it to execute, simply because :

1) the java code that you write has to be compiled if it has to run.
2) resources are compiled into a different form so that android doesn't have to parse the XML (costly operation) everytime.

The basic use of strings.xml is for internationalization (code for ur app will not change even if you have to add support for multiple languages). IMO, there is no valid reason to write java code in an XML file.