# Call function in string.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a method in a class and would like to know if it is possible to call said method in  `strings.xml` like this:

```
<xml>
  <string name="title"> getValue(Hello Word) </string>
<xml>
```

Comment: I guess you can't. Its considered as a string resource

Comment: You can't call functions from xml !

Comment: function calling from xml not possible.

Comment: Basically I want to create multi language based on xml that created by back end system. In Android I have created function to read that XML, but some developers have defined that text in strings.xml, just figure it out if I can use that function on that xml. I didn't use string resources because I want the xml files can generated by others application and more easier to maintenance the word, if the application have run and need some new word I just generate and parse the xml files and the application have no impact.

Comment: I guess you could if you compiled it e.g. with ruby foo.xml.erb

Answer (score 1):

If you're not trying to do reflection, I don't know what you're trying to do. See [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). I have no idea what your use case is, but it's probably inappropriate.

Comment: just share with you that I want to develop.
Basically I want to create multi language based on xml that created by back end system. In Android I have created function to read that XML, but some developers have defined that text in strings.xml, just figure it out if I can use that function on that xml. I didn't use string resources because I want the xml files can generated by others application and more easier to maintenance the word, if the application have run and need some new word I just generate and parse the xml files and the application have no impact.

Answer (score 1):

NO, you cant evaluate anything inside `Strings.xml`.

Classes and resources are compiled in different manners. Resources are compiled in such a way that they need not to be parsed again and again.

But to execute java code, you need to compile it.

So you can write java code inside Strings.xml, but anyhow it would only be dead code with no use of it.

Comment: Thanks all, very appreciated. Basically I want to create multi language based on xml that created by back end system.

In Android I have created function to read that XML, but some developers have defined that text in strings.xml, just figure it out if I can use that function on that xml. I didn't use string resources because I want the xml files can generated by others application and more easier to maintenance the word, if the application have run and need some new word I just generate and parse the xml files and the application have no impact.

Comment: if you want to do this, you can first fetch the string resource, alter its value by calling the function and then you can use shared prefences or database to store that string.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you can have a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11184505/1626878